# Nativescript how force webpack to clear cached node_module?

Tags: webpack, nativescript

There is a little issue with some nativescript module .. and I fixed it, but the webpack was cached those module beacuse hi write same error on CLI.

I tried to remove, update webpack module and `platforms` `hooks` .. tried also remove `node_modules` fix the error with new run but I can not...

```
/node_modules/nativescript-filterable-listpicker/index.d.ts(31,9):
TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your app/package.json have codeCache set to true?
or have you enabled any caching mechanism on your webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Hi @ShivaPrasad, not I have not enabled some think .. I just upgrade my NS to 6.3 and also `nativescript-dev-webpack@latest` .. what is the config key should I search on webpack.config.js ?